# Anaconda prompt not displaying (base) environment, displays path instead

Tags: anaconda

I just did a more or less clean install of `Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe`. I selected the "All users" option to avoid admin rights problems with packages such as `jupyter`. The program was installed into `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`.

When I open the Anaconda prompt, `conda` returns the following output, however it doesn't recognize the `base` environment the way I would like it to, instead I get this on my prompt:

```
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\Users\aboufira>
```

When I really expect this:

```
(base) C:\Users\aboufira>
```

I find this problem to be quite annoying. Why does this occur? Have I installed into the wrong directory? How can I get it to display `base` like it should?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your .condarc-file located at C:/Users/User and restart navigator again - worked for me :)